# Compiling a gnu program without sse3

Tags: c++, configure, sse3

I'm compiling an app for a device where the architecture does not support sse beyond sse2, and was wondering is it possible to disable compiling with sse3 instructions from GNU autoconf generated configure scripts? I know you can turn it off in gcc/g++ with mno-sse3 option, but it would be nice if I could turn it off at the configuration level rather than generating a make file and then manually inserting that compiler flag...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure. Just set the required flags before calling configure:

```
$ CFLAGS="-mtune i386" ./configure --enable-this --disable-that ...
```

You might want to try -march if [-mtune](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/i386-and-x86_002d64-Options.html) does the wrong thing, I haven't tested this lately.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using the more recent versions of gcc, you can simply do `-march=native`, and the compiler will handle it for you.

**Edit:** this option was introduced in [gcc 4.2](http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.2/changes.html).